# Sample Programs for Design Pattern Recover Tool

Tags: java, design-patterns, reverse-engineering, static-analysis

I'm developing a Design Pattern Recovery tool for my final year project. It is a java based system which can be used in identifying, implemented design patterns in a particular java program. When you input the java program (Source code) to the design pattern recovery tool, it analyzes the static and dynamic features of the java program and identify the implemented design patterns.

So far, i have been using dummy projects to test the functionality of the tool. But, now i need sample programs with proper documentations about the implemented design patterns to  test the tool. I want to know, where i can find such programs (with source code) so that i can test my system properly.

I know this is a bit of broad question. What  i need is sample java programs to test my tool. In order to ensure the accuracy of the results, those programs should have proper documentation about the implementations details specially about the design patterns used.

Comment: Way too long question, **github.com**.

Answer (score 0):

I would look for some open source java projects. Must be many [out](https://www.google.nl/search?q=java%20opensource) [there](http://java-source.net/).